# Content of p dialog (Primefaces) is empty in IE8

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-8, weblogic12c

So, we are undergoing very strange issue and would like to see if anyone else went through this. We have built an application using Primefaces 4.0, JSF 2.1.27 Mojarra. Deployed onto WL 12.1.1. Tested in IE8.

So, there is a Profile page and it has a dialog, when user clicks on Edit Profile, a dialog shows up with a form , the user edits information and then saves it, the dialog closes and then updated information is shown on the page.

So when I run it on my local weblogic 12.1.1, everything works absolutely fine. And not only me, couple of other colleagues tested it too, it works fine in their local WL too and IE8,Chrome etc

So, we deployed to our company's DEV server which is WL 12.1.2, and then tested in IE8, when we click on that edit profile p commandLink, the dialog opens up with no content inside it.Its just the dialog. And it works on other browsers well and good.

The only change I see is the server.

Here is the code for commandLink on that page :

```
<p:commandLink value="Edit Profile Info"
                    oncomplete="PF('profileInfoDialog').show()" update=":editProfileForm" 
                    style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;font-style:italic" />
```

Here is the dialog , the content is long code but, I dont think content has anything to do with it :

```
<p:dialog header="Edit Profile Info" widgetVar="profileInfoDialog" closable="false"
        style="border:1px 0" modal="true" appendToBody="true" id="profileInfoDialogId" dynamic="true">
            <h:form id="editProfileForm">
       //All the input fields and other content
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Save"
                            partialSubmit="true" validateClient="true"
                            update=":editProfileForm:messages"
                            actionListener="#{profileInfoBean.saveProfile}"
                            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed  &amp;&amp; args.saved) PF('profileInfoDialog').hide();"/>
                        <h:outputText
                            value="By clicking Save, I verify the information on this screen is accurate." />
                        <p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" type="button" update="editProfileForm"
                            onclick="PF('profileInfoDialog').hide();">
                             <p:resetInput target="editProfileForm" />
                            </p:commandButton>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

The reason I am stressing on server version is, I just tried on one of my friend's local weblogic server 12.1.2, and he has the same issue with IE.
I already tried removing modal=true and appendToBody=true, but nothing worked. I really appreciate help here as we are heading to QA and this has become a roadblock.

Thanks!

Comment: Press F12 and check what is the Document Mode. If it is Quirks mode then change it to IE8.

Comment: Your right! That worked, I also found a fix that could force from the App itself.Im gonna post it soon! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Makky : Thanks for helping me diagnose the problem!

This worked for me :

```
<h:head>

<f:facet name="first">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" />

</f:facet>

</h:head>
```